# Sum of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+\cdots \cdots \cdots +\frac{n}{n^2+n}\right)$

Tags: limits, summation

Sum of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+\cdots \cdots \cdots +\frac{n}{n^2+n}\right)$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ I have solved it  using Squeeze theorem

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{n}{n^2+n}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{n}{n^2+r}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{n}{n^2+1}$$

So we get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{n}{n^2+r} = 1$$

My question is can we solve above limit without using Squeeze Theorem,

If yes then plz explian me, Thanks

Comment: You mean, finding *more* complicated and *less* enlightening ways? What for?

Comment: Use Riemann sum instead

Comment: You have the sum of $n$ terms bounded between $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$, so it is trivial that the limit is $1$. What is the reason for looking for more involved approaches?

Comment: This question is about the same sum: [Convergence of a sequence, $a_n=\sum_1^nn/(n^2+k)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/77909). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7Bn%5E2%2Bk%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using harmonic numbers $$S_n=\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{n}{n^2+r}=n \left(H_{n^2+n}-H_{n^2}\right)$$ Now, using the expansion $$H_p=\gamma+\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p ^4}\right)$$ and applying to each term  you should arrive to $$S_n=n\left(\frac{-6 n^3-6 n^2+2 n+1}{12 n^4 (n+1)^2}+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n ^2}\right)\right)$$ Taylor again,  $$S_n=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n ^2}\right)$$

**Edit**

May be of interest
$$T_n=\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{n}{n^k+r}=n \left(H_{n^k+n}-H_{n^k}\right)$$ leads to $$T_n=\frac{ \left(n^{2-k}-6 n^{k+1}-6 n^2+2 n\right)}{12 n^k\left(n^k+n\right)^2}+\log \left(1+\frac 1 {n^{k-1}}\right)$$ which makes $$n^{k-1}T_n=1-\frac{1}{2 n^{k-1}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^k}\right)$$