# Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left({x \over x^2+1}+{x \over x^2+2}+\cdots +{x\over x^2+x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left({x \over x^2+1}+{x  \over x^2+2}+\cdots +{x\over x^2+x}\right)$$ , without using squeeze theorem.
I have done the solution as below using squeeze theorem ...
$$Let \left[\left({x \over x^2+1}+{x  \over x^2+2}+\cdots +{x\over x^2+x}\right)\right]=f(x)\implies \\  \left({x \over x^2+x}+{x  \over x^2+x}+\cdots +{x\over x^2+x}\right)\lt f(x)\lt \left({x \over x^2+1}+{x  \over x^2+1}+\cdots +{x\over x^2+1}\right) \\ {x^2 \over x+x^2}\lt f(x) \lt {x^2\over 1+x^2}\\ \text{applying limit on both sides }\\ \implies\lim_{x\to \infty}{x^2 \over x+x^2}= \lim_{x\to \infty}{x^2\over 1+x^2}=1\\ \implies \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$$ 
Can we do this without squeeze theorem?

Comment: Squeeze theorem is one of the most fundamental tools in limits. Its proof is very straightforward, and it codifies the idea of estimating using inequalities, which is really the essence of computating all limits. What I'm trying to say, is that avoiding using it is an odd, and somewhat artificial request. Is there any particular reason to avoid using it? Were you looking for, say, a method involving finding the closed form of the sum instead?

Comment: Is $x$ an integer?

Comment: @TheoBendit This was part of my old assignment. I was just wondering is there some other way to do this. Just curiosity , nothing else. I'm still in highschool.

Comment: see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995860/sum-of-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-left-fracnn21-fracnn22-cdots?rq=1)

Comment: @JackyChong no ,but a real number .

Comment: @ChinnapparajR  sorry , but while asking , I couldn't find this question.

Comment: That's no problem!

Comment: @SubhajitHalder  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could do it using harmonic numbers
$$S_x=\sum_{k=1}^x \frac x {x^2+k}=x\sum_{k=1}^x \frac 1 {x^2+k}=x \left(H_{x^2+x}-H_{x^2}\right)$$
Now, using the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ we should get
$$S_x=1-\frac{1}{2 x}-\frac{1}{6 x^2}+\frac{1}{4
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$

Comment: Getting older has its own benefits! great Claude+

Comment: @mrs. Just out of curiosity, are you kidding the old man ? (joke for sure !). Cheers and thanks.

Comment: @Claude You have already answered a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1995904/578155), why answer it again ?

Comment: @paulplusx. I did not remember that ! Problem of age, I guess !!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Nice derivation! I obtain $S_x=\sim 1-\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{x}{3x^{2}}+\ldots$ but I can't see why. Any idea?

Comment: @gimusi. Thanks. Doing it your way, I get the same (as in my answer) using the full Faulhaber's formulae.

Comment: Thanks Claude, I check again my derivation! Bye

Comment: Ah yes of course I’m neglecting some terms and both are valid asymptotics to find the limit but your one is exact up to the 1/x^3 term, mine only up to 1/x term. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @gimusi. You are welcome ! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

By geometric series we have

$$\frac x {x^2+k}=\frac1x\frac 1 {1+k/x^2}=$$$$=\frac1x\left(1-\frac{k}{x^{2}}+\left(-\frac{k}{x^{2}}\right)^2+\ldots\right)=\frac1x-\frac{k}{x^{3}}+\frac{k^2}{x^{5}}+\ldots$$

and therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^x \frac x {x^2+k}=\sum_{k=1}^x \left(\frac1x-\frac{k}{x^{3}}+\frac{k^2}{x^{5}}+\ldots\right)=1-\frac{\sum_{k=1}^xk}{x^{3}}+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^xk^2}{x^{5}}+\ldots $$

$$\sim 1-\frac{x^2}{2x^{3}}+\frac{x^3}{3x^{5}}+\ldots\to 1$$

indeed recall that by [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

$$\sum_{k=1}^xk^p \sim \frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Take, $\displaystyle a_{x,n}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+n}$. Then use Cauchy's First limit theorem.

As $a_{x,n} \to 1$ when $x\to \infty$, so $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{x}a_{x,n} \to 1$ when $x\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**With a Riemannian sum:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k}=n\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\dfrac k{n^2}}$$ can be seen as a Riemaniann sum truncated to the $n$ first terms among $n^2$. Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^{1/n}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=1.$$

No quite rigorous, though (because the sum converges to the integral at the same time that we increase $n$).

Answer (score 0):

Just using that $\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}=1-\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

So $$\frac{x}{x^2+c}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{x^2}{x^2+c}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+\frac{c}{x^2}}=\frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{c}{x^2}+O(\frac{c}{x^4})\right)$$

$$\sum_{c=1}^x\frac{x}{x^2+c}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{c=1}^x1-\frac{c}{x^2}+O(\frac{c}{x^4})=1-\frac{x (x+1)}{2x^3}+O(\frac{1}{x^2})=1-\frac{1}{2x}+O(\frac{1}{x^2})$$

Note that using $\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}=1+O(\epsilon)$ is in fact enough and simpler here, but you don't get the $\frac{-1}{2x}$, only $O(\frac{1}{x})$