Limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k}$
Im having trouble with the following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k}.$$ If it were $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k^2},$$ it would be simply approximated by the integral $$\int_0^1f(x)dx,$$ with $f(x)=1/(1+x^2),$ but the fact of $k$ not being squared its giving me trouble, and i don't know how to calculate it. Any idea? Thanks in advance

You can use that $\frac{n}{n^2+k^2} < \frac{n}{n^2+k} < \frac{1}{n}$

We have $${n\over n^2+n}\le {n\over n^2+k}\le {1\over n}$$ Thus the sum is located between ${n^2\over n^2+n}$ and $1.$ Hence the limit is equal $1.$
More generally the sum with terms ${n\over n^2+k^a}$ tends to $1$ for $a<2$ and to $0$ for $a>2.$
The case $a<2$ can be treated the same way as for $a=1.$ Assume $a>2.$ There is $b<1$ such that $ab>2$ (for instance $b=\sqrt{2a^{-1}}).$  Fix $1\le N_b<n.$ The value of $N_b$ will be specified later. We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{n\over n^2+k^a}=\sum_{k=1}^{N_b}{n\over n^2+k^a}+\sum_{k=N_b+1}^n{n\over n^2+k^a}\\ \le \sum_{n=1}^{N_b}{1\over n}+\sum_{k=N_b+1}^n{n\over k^a}
\le {N_b\over n}+{n^2\over N_b^a}$$ Let $N_b=\lceil n^b\rceil.$ Then ${N_b\over n}\le {n^b+1\over n}\to 0.$ On the other hand $${n^2\over N_b^a}\le {n^2\over (n^b)^a}={n^2\over n^{ab}}\to 0$$
An alternative proof:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{n\over n^2+k^a} ={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n{n^a\over n^a+n^{a-2}k^a}={1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over 1+n^{a-2}\left ({k\over n}\right )^a}\\
\le \int\limits_0^1{1\over 1+n^{a-2}x^a}\,dx\underset{n}{\longrightarrow}0$$
We have used the property: if $ f$ is decreasing then
$${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left ({k\over n}\right )\le \int\limits_0^1f(x)\,dx$$

When $a>2$, can you give a proof of $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n\over n^2+k^a}\to0?$$ I can prove this by $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n\over n^2+k^a}<\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac{n}{n^2+x^a}dx\to0,$$ which needs complicated computation(for example $a=3$)!

@Riemann I have extended the answer in order to cover the case $a>2.$

@
Ryszard Szwarc
Thanks, nice proof. Actually taking $b\in(2/a,1)$ would be OK!
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k^a}
&=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n^b}\frac{n}{n^2+k^a}
+\sum_{n^b<k\leq n}\frac{n}{n^2+k^a}\
&<\sum_{1\leq k\leq n^b}\frac{n}{n^2}
+\sum_{n^b<k\leq n}\frac{n}{k^a}\
&<\frac{1}{n^{1-b}}+\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\frac{n}{n^{ab}}\
&=\frac{1}{n^{1-b}}+\frac{1}{n^{ab-2}}\
&\to0\quad (n\to\infty).
\end{align*}

If you use harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k}=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n^2+k}=n \left(H_{n^2+n}-H_{n^2}\right)$$ If you use the series expansion
$$H_p=\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12p^2}
+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ apply it twice and continue with Taylor series to have more than the limit
$$S_n=1-\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{6 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

it's a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1995904/42969

As an alternative to the fine method proposed we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k} =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^3+nk}\to1+0=1$$
indeed
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^3+nk} \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^3}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^3}\to 0$$

Be careful when you take the sum of O terms. You need to show that the constants for each do not vary much.

@martycohen Yes indeed this was a step I was thinking about. How would you suggest to improve this step? Thanks

@martycohen I've changed a little bit using another way!
