# find the point of convergence of sequence {$a_n$}

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $\displaystyle a_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{n^2+k}$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then what is the nature of sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

I tried using the Cauchy's general principle of converges for a sequence. But I think that this won't help me as because:

$\displaystyle a_{n+p}= \sum_{k=1}^{n+p} \frac{n+p}{{(n+p)}^2+k}$ and $\displaystyle a_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{n^2+k}$

And now if I do $a_{n+p}-a_{n}$ then this won't even cancel a single term.

$a_1$ will have one term.

$a_2$ will have two terms, and so on.

But here the first term in $a_2$ is not the term of $a_1$.

and due to this problem I was unable to use any results of convergence of series of positive terms.

Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77909, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1995860 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdisplaystyle%20a_n%3D%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7Bn%5E2%2Bk%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try sandwiching $a_n$.

> $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2 + k} \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} = 1.$$
>  $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2 + k} \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n + 1} = \frac{n}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $1\le k\le n$ :$${n\over n^2+n}\le {n\over n^2+k}\le {n\over n^2+1}$$therefore $${n^2\over n^2+n}\le a_n\le {n^2\over n^2+1}$$and bu squeeze theorem$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=1$$

[image]

Comment: Already posted by another user, right?